# Issue with $PYTHONPATH

Tags: python-3.x, pythonpath

I get the following message when trying to run `virtualenv . --no-site-packages`

```
You are attempting to install a package to a directory that is not
on PYTHONPATH and which Python does not read ".pth" files from.  The
installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/

and your PYTHONPATH environment variable currently contains:

    ''
```

However, when I echo my PYTHONPATH, I see the path from the default setting:

```
/usr/local/python-3.3.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/
```

So my PYTHONPATH does contain the directory I am installing to.

Anyone have any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to use virtualenv-3.3, not virtualenv.